# Alphanumeric and numeric strings sorting not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

I implemented below logic to apply sorting on mixed data(contains alphanumeric and numeric values) but it is not sorting as expected.

> ```
> /*For numeric value sorting */
> ```

```
if (!isNaN(fVal) && !isNaN(lastVal)) {
    switch (policy) {
        case SORT_BY_DESC:
            return +fVal < +lastVal ? 1 : -1;
        case SORT_BY_ASC:
            return +fVal > +lastVal ? 1 : -1;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
} 
/* For alphanumeric sorting */
else {
    switch (policy) {
        case SORT_BY_DESC:
            return fVal < lastVal ? 1 : -1;
        case SORT_BY_ASC:
            return fVal > lastVal ? 1 : -1;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}
```

If all the values are numeric this logic is working fine but if I have mixed data it is not sorting properly.

Raw Data - ['60091A0222', '633', '63372A1019', '63372A1021', '6667', '6789', '7776']

**Expected Result -**

Data in Descending order  - 63372A1021,
63372A1019,
60091A0222,
7776,
6789,
633

Data in Ascending order - 633,,
6667,
6789,
7776,
60091A0222,
63372A1019,
63372A1021

**What I am getting -**

Descending order - 7776,
6789,
6667,
63372A1021,
63372A1019,
633,
60091A0222

Ascending order - 60091A0222,
633,
63372A1019,
63372A1021,
6667,
6789,
7776

Comment: please add raw data in literal notation.

Comment: Can you articulate the rules on how the values should be sorted. You wrote the code, but by your own words, the code doesn't sort correctly, so the rules that the code represents ain't correct. What are the correct rules? From the expected results I thought, for asc: `['60091A0222', '633', '63372A1019', '63372A1021', '6667', '6789', '7776'].sort((a,b) => parseInt(a) - parseInt(b))` but does this sort right or does this just accidently produce the right result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue with your current code is that the if-statement only accounts for 2 scenarios.

1. Both values are not `NaN`.
2. Both values are `NaN`.

You have not specified what should happens if one value is a number and the other one is a non-number. They currently fall into the else-logic and are ordered based on ASCII values.

However from you desired output it seems that you first want to order based on the number/non-number. This is then followed by either a value comparison for the number values, or an ASCII code-point comparison for non-number values.

With a minimum amount of changes to your current code, this might look like this:

```js
// one value is a number, the other one is not
if (isNaN(fVal) !== isNaN(lastVal)) {
    switch (policy) {
        case SORT_BY_DESC:
            return isNaN(fVal) ? -1 : 1; // move non-numbers to the front
        case SORT_BY_ASC:
            return isNaN(fVal) ? 1 : -1; // move non-numbers to the back
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}

// both values are numbers
if (!isNaN(fVal) && !isNaN(lastVal)) { // <- One check is obsolete. We know that
    switch (policy) {                  //    either both are a number, or both are
        case SORT_BY_DESC:             //    a non-number, so one check suffices.
            return +fVal < +lastVal ? 1 : -1;
        case SORT_BY_ASC:
            return +fVal > +lastVal ? 1 : -1;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}

// both values are non-numbers
/* For alphanumeric sorting */
else { // <- Obsolete else, every path in the if returns the function.
    switch (policy) {
        case SORT_BY_DESC:
            return fVal < lastVal ? 1 : -1;
        case SORT_BY_ASC:
            return fVal > lastVal ? 1 : -1;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, if I want to apply sorting on special character then what changes I need to add in my code? For example if values are - ['1234', '-qwert47u5', 'A169154-0722', '5678', '45 HJ-$&']

Comment: What qualifies as a *special character*? Is `-` a special character? Are `$` and `&` special characters? How do you want to sort values that have special characters in them? What should be the sorting order? `contains-special, is-number, (number-value OR string-code-point-value)`

Comment: @user1881845 this it now outside the scope of the original question. You should create a new question.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a check for finiteness and sort this value to top.

```js
const
    data = ['60091A0222', '833', '63372A1019', '63372A1021', '6667', '6789', '7776'],
    asc = (a, b) => isFinite(b) - isFinite(a) || (+a > +b) - (+a < +b) || (a > b) - (a < b),
    desc = (a, b) => asc(b, a);

data.sort(asc);
console.log(...data);

data.sort(desc);
console.log(...data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to split the strings into number/letter/number groups and sort based on the presence of each type of group.

```js
const sortIndices = (data, desc = false) => {
  const pattern = /(?<=\d)(?=\D)|(?=\d)(?<=\D)/, dir = desc ? -1 : 1;
  return data.sort((a, b) => {
    const x = a.split(pattern), y = b.split(pattern);
    let diff;
    // Compare overall length
    if (a.length < b.length) return -1 * dir;
    if (b.length < a.length) return 1 * dir;
    // Find the difference between the first group (numeric)
    diff = +x[0] - +y[0];
    if (diff !== 0) return diff * dir;
    // If both contain at least two groups
    if (a.length < 2) return -1 * dir;
    if (b.length < 2) return 1 * dir;
    // Find the difference between the second group (alpha)
    diff = x[1].localeCompare(y[1]);
    if (diff !== 0) return diff * dir;
    // If both contain at least three groups
    if (a.length < 3) return -1 * dir;
    if (b.length < 3) return 1 * dir;
    // Find the difference between the third group (numeric)
    return (+x[2] - +y[2]) * dir;
  });
};

const arr = ['60091A0222', '633', '63372A1019', '63372A1021', '6667', '6789', '7776'];

console.log(...sortIndices(arr));       // Ascending
console.log(...sortIndices(arr, true)); // Descending
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```